# Unable to load images from static folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

How can I load images in a component in Next.js? Do I have to build the project first? If yes, is there a way to load the images without building first? I cannot get this to work, no matter what I try.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

[from the docs:](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called
> public in the root directory. Files inside public can then be
> referenced by your code starting from the base URL (/).

So, first add an image to `public/my-image.png` and then you can reference it:

```
<img src="/my-image.png" />
```

I think next.js will have a watch on this directory so you won't need to re`start` your server every time you put something in there.

Comment: To explicit the difference, it's about no importation, just direct mention in files

Comment: This answer is contains depreciated content. Please follow [this documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) instead.

Comment: Does it work when trying to load static images into dynamic files - i.e ```/pages/stuff/[id].js``` Using the root Public folder is not working on these cases

Comment: @aliosh yes that seems to be the case for me too

Comment: it is not working with Image rather than img

Answer (score 18):

The static directory has been deprecated. Place files in `public/static` directory

Comment: Yes this works, e.g. I put mine in `public/static/images/icons/x.svg` , and this works in my image tag `<img src="/static/images/icons/x.svg"/>`

Answer (score 15):

From Next.js v11 onwards, one can now directly `import` images without any additional config or dependencies. Official example (comment mine):

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
import profilePic from '../public/me.png'

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>My Homepage</h1>
      <Image src={profilePic} alt="Picture of the author" />
      {/* <img src={profilePic.src} alt="Picture of the author" /> */}
      <p>Welcome to my homepage!</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Docs: [`next/image`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

Answer (score 11):

Another way I find out [Next Images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-images)

**installation**: 
`npm install --save next-images`

or
 `yarn add next-images`

**Usage**:

Create a `next.config.js` in your project

```
// next.config.js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages()
```

Optionally you can add your custom Next.js configuration as parameter

```
// next.config.js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages({
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config
  }
})
```

And in your components or pages simply import your images:

```
export default () => <div>
  <img src={require('./my-image.jpg')} />
</div>
```

or

```
import myImg from './my-image.jpg'

export default () => <div>
  <img src={myImg} />
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work when trying to load static images into dynamic files - i.e ```/pages/stuff/[id].js``` Using the root Public folder is not working on these cases

Comment: i cant thank you enough for this. One Love

Comment: This solution woked for me. placing images on 'public' folder will work. but if you keep images other than public folder like 'assets' then configuring things on next.config.js will work smoothly. thank you

Comment: when i use the require statement in my image source i always get TypeError: src.startsWith is not a function which is a rabbit hole issue. Upgrade webpack -> upgrade next.js  -> webpack version not compatible with next.js

Comment: @gage Next.js projects are modules based it's required to use `import` instead of `require`.

Answer (score 3):

what i like to do for directing to images is using `environment variables`. in next.js they are easily set in `next.config.js` file like below:

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
    env: {
      PUBLIC_URL: '/',
    }
};
```

then you can direct to your publics path wherever it is by using `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` like below:

```
<img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/my-image.jpg`} />
```

the advantages of using PUBLIC_URL environment variable over hard coding the path is that you can use another path for when file arrangements change (like in server). for then you could set conditionally which PUBLIC_URL value to use in production and development.

---

### update

sometimes the problem of images used with next/Image not showing is bc of not setting the right `layout` value or it lacks `width` and `height` attributes when used with `layout` other than `fill`.

Using Image component of Next.js version 13 is a little bit different than than its previous versions. It's actually easier and you can use optimization features with less effort and work arounds. In this version :

- you're not obligated to set `domains` in `next.config.js`.
- you can either set the image its width and height or set to `fill` and handle its sizing with styles or classNames which means you can set max-height or max-width. so in that case that you don't know your image's width and height it's be shown properly.
- as well as its previous versions you can use `priority` and ...

Answer (score 2):

With Next 10+
To serve an optimized image:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
<Image src={'banner.jpg'} alt='Home Page' width={100} height={100} />
```

Place the image in the public folder. All the referenced images must be present in the public folder at the build time. Image hot deployment will not work for images that reside in the public folder.
You also can refer to cross-domain images with `<Image>` tag.

```
<Image src={'https://www.example.com/banner.jpg'} alt='Home Page' width={100} height={100} />
```

To allow cross-domain images, ensure to add the below entry to your `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
images: {
    domains: ['www.example.com'],
},
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I will add here one obvious case, that is usually easily forgotten. It keeps appearing when one re-structure a site page and our IDE "silently fails" to update the paths of a related file/component or simply when one is more tired or distracted.

If you are using a page inside a folder
ex: `mysiteDomain/pagefolder/page`
You should be careful when using relative path.
Something like `<img src="logo.png" />` should be changed it to `<img src="../logo.png" />` since the compiled page will also be inside a folder `pagefolder`.
The path in the `src` attribute will be relative to the compiled page.

As an alternative, you could simply use an absolute path like for ex `<img src="/logo.png" />`. The path in the `src` attribute will be relative to the compiled root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT put `public` into `/src`!

In my case, I had a `src` dir into which I put my `pages` etc., which is an option described [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/src-directory). But I ALSO accidentally moved the `public` dir there. This will mess nextjs up -- you need to keep `public` in the root dir.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Image tag like below worked for me

```
import Image from 'next/image'
```

Answer (score -3):

After running `next build && next export` and your images are not visible do this:

```
// next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  images: {
    loader: "custom",
    loaderFile: "./imageLoader.js",
  },

  assetPrefix: "./",

  env: {
    // dev does not need static path
    ROOTDIR: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "" : "file:///C:/Users/.../out",
  },
};
```

Create an imageLoader.js too in the root project

```
export default function imageLoader({ src, width, quality }) {
  return `process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "" : "file:///C:/Users/.../out${src}?w=${width}?q=${quality || 75}`;
}
```

Where *file:///C:/Users/.../out* refers to full path to the root of your build

Now you can append process.env.ROOT before "/*"

Answer (score -3):

I have faced the same problem the point which we should check while using Next js.

1. Image should be available
2. Image should be present in public directory.
3. Public directory should be present in those folder in which node module is present
   The thing which I did wrong is I placed the folder in public due to which my image was not showing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).